# How would I get a single string from the result of a razor foreach loop? (preferably not Linq)

Tags: string, razor, foreach, umbraco

(hope everyone's well).

Please could I get some advice on how best to get a single string as a variable from the following foreach loop with razor (preferably not Linq)...

```
        @if (selection.Any())
        {
            foreach(var item in selection){
                foreach (var searchLocationItem in item.searchLocation)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLocationItem)){                                                         
                        counter++;
                        @searchLocationItem<text>,</text>;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The above code outputs a string exactly as I require, but as html, not a reusable variable.

Any help on how to get the result efficiently as a single string variable would be appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stringbuilder:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var item in selection){
    foreach (var searchLocationItem in item.searchLocation)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLocationItem)){                                                         
            counter++;
            builder.Append(String.Format("{0}<text>,</text>;", searchLocationItem));
        }
    }
}

@builder.ToString()
```